# scrollOverflow not working in fullPage.js

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, fullpage.js

I recently began using fullPage.js for a project, and I cannot figure out how to get the overflow scrolling to work. The last 'section' in my page runs long, and as such, needs vertical scrolling.

Here is the code I have inside my `<head>` tags:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>      
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.fullPage.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $.fn.fullpage({
                anchors: ['top', 'brand-or-agency', 'contact-us'],
                fixedElements: '#header',
                resize: false,
                scrollOverflow: true,
                css3: true,
                paddingTop: 100,
                loopTop: false
            });
        });
    </script>
```

I am also using Bootstrap (including the JS), as well as jQuery validate.

Is there anything else I'm missing here to enable this feature?

Comment: It doesn't look bad. Are you getting any error in the javascript console? Are you importing properly the `slimscroll` plugin? Could you reproduce your problem in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or add a link or us to see it?

Comment: Also if you're having some issues maybe check out OverThrow from the filament group: https://github.com/filamentgroup/Overthrow

Comment: If you're still running the issue, I've provided an answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/22305075/1260424 which solved mine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scrollbar on active slide for overflowing content with Fullpage.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21817799/scrollbar-on-active-slide-for-overflowing-content-with-fullpage-js)

Comment: You should provide us with more information. Ideally with a reproduction of your problem. Take into account that if the content is absolute positioned the plugin won't be able to detect the section height as the content of it won't have any influence on the section final height.

Answer (score -1):

> Is there anything else I'm missing here to enable this feature?

If i understand it correctly, all you are missing out on is the option called **normalScrollElements**. It is a class/id you define and then add to the div element.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.fn.fullpage({
            anchors: ['top', 'brand-or-agency', 'contact-us'],
            fixedElements: '#header',
            resize: false,
            scrollOverflow: true,
            css3: true,
            paddingTop: 100,
            loopTop: false,
            normalScrollElements: '#element, .element'

        });
    });
```

HTML

```
<div class='section element'> This section will scroll vertically </div>
```

As you can see the sectionSelector "section" still needs to be applied.

Comment: Nop, it has nothing to do with it. He is looking to apply `scrollOverflow`.

Comment: That helped me with my prob! Thanks!