# scrollOverflow / slimScroll not working properly in fullPage.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullpage.js, slimscroll

This is the sequel of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20111272/scrolloverflow-not-working-in-fullpage-js) thread.

On one page of the website I'm building for a client, both fullpage navigation and scrolloverflow/slimscroll work fine.

On another page, fullpage nav works but the overflow is not scrolling. Looks like the two divs with the class `.slimScrollDiv` and `.scrollable` are not being created as expected.
Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7PwsS/328/) ; the `scrollOverflow` is set to `true` yet the overflow of the second section does not scroll.

```
$.fn.fullpage({
    scrollOverflow: true
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are having troubles because the class `.infotext` wrapping your table is defined with `position:absolute`. 
This way the plugin can not detect the height of the section content and therefore I doesn't realize it has to create the scrollbar.

Use `position:relative` instead and the problem will be solved:

[**Live demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/7PwsS/329/)

Using an absolute positioned element doesn't make much sense as it will be relative to the section as if you were using a relative positioned one.